# how to use str_detect being FALSE in a if statement r to append a value

Tags: r, string, if-statement, append, stringr

I have the following vector of hashtags:

```
hashtags <- c("#data", "#datascience", "#datascienceiscool")
```

And I'm trying to write a code that says if a string is NOT present (in this example, let's say "#datascienceinR"), then append it to the vector. If it is there, no other action needs to be taken. I've tried this:

```
library(tidyverse)
all_hashtags <- if(str_detect(hashtags, "#datascienceinR") = FALSE) {
  append(hashtags, "#datascienceinR")
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "all_hashtags <- if(str_detect(hashtags, "#datascienceinR") ="
>   append(hashtags, "#datascienceinR")
[1] "#data"             
[2] "#datascience"      
[3] "#datascienceiscool"
[4] "#datascienceinR"   
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=` is assignment operator and not `==` (comparison operator)

```
if(str_detect(hashtags, "#datascienceinR") = FALSE)
                                           ^
```

Also, instead of doing the `==` FALSE, it is better to negate (`!`)

```
!str_detect(hashtags, "#datascienceinR")
```

Third issue is the use of `if/else` as `if/else` expects a logical vector of length 1 and not more than one.  Here, the 'hashtags' is a vector of length 3 and the `str_detect` also returns the same length of TRUE/FALSE logical vector.  So, we need to wrap with `all`

```
all_hashtags <- if(all(!str_detect(hashtags, "#datascienceinR"))) {
       append(hashtags, "#datascienceinR")
 } 

all_hashtags
#[1] "#data"              "#datascience"       "#datascienceiscool" "#datascienceinR"
```

---

It can also be written with `union` (assuming there are no duplicate elements)

```
hashtags <- union(hashtags, "datascienceinR")
```

If there are duplicate elements andd want to keep them, another option is `vunion` from `vecsets`

```
library(vecsets)
hashtags <- vunion(hashtags, "datascienceinR")
```

Comment: thank you! I really appreciate all the different options and walking through the steps